# Restricting edits for collections of value types in general (and in PropertyGrid)

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, properties, propertygrid

My class has a collection of boolean values. I'd like to allow changing the values, but restrict adding or removing them. (specifically in PropertyGrid control).

So far I've googled

```
.AsReadOnly()
```

method as a recommended solution, but it works differently with сollections of value types (adds/removes restricted, but changed values aren't saved) as compared to collections of reference types (adds/removes restricted, changed values successfully saved).

I made a short example for this behaviour:
Consider a class wrapping boolean values:

```
class boolWrapper
{
    public bool boolValue { get; set; }

    public boolWrapper (bool boolValue)
    {
        this.boolValue = boolValue;
    }
}
```

And some other class to use both kinds of Collections:

```
class testClassWithArray
{
    // Collection of booleans
    private List<bool> _boolArray;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<bool> boolArray
    {
        get { return _boolArray.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    // Collection of wrapped booleans
    private List<boolWrapper> _boolWrappedArray;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<boolWrapper> boolWrappedArray
    {
        get { return _boolWrappedArray.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    // Filling collections with some values
    public testClassWithArray()
    {
        _boolArray = new List<bool>();
        _boolWrappedArray = new List<boolWrapper>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            _boolArray.Add(false);
            _boolWrappedArray.Add(new boolWrapper(false));
        }
    }
}
```

Let's assign to a PropertyGrid:

```
        testClassWithArray testArr = new testClassWithArray();
        testPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = testArr;
```

When changing values for both collections (boolWrappedArray, boolArray), new values are successfully applied by the collection of wrapped values, but not the other one.

While this behaviour may be understandable, is there a way to do without a wrapper class, restrict add/remove operations and apply new values for the collection of value types?

Answer (score 0):

> While this behaviour may be understandable, is there a way to do without a wrapper class, restrict add/remove operations and apply new values for the collection of value types?

Although not recommended in general, the easiest way to accomplish what you are asking for is to expose such collections as `Array` (no add/remove, just edit, unfortunately w/o any control (validation)), like this

```
class testClassWithArray
{
    // Collection of booleans
    public bool[] boolArray { get; private set; }

    // Collection of wrapped booleans
    private List<boolWrapper> _boolWrappedArray;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<boolWrapper> boolWrappedArray
    {
        get { return _boolWrappedArray.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    // Filling collections with some values
    public testClassWithArray()
    {
        boolArray = new bool[3];
        _boolWrappedArray = new List<boolWrapper>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            _boolWrappedArray.Add(new boolWrapper(false));
        }
    }
}
```